# elasticsearh how to find the percentage of document that has less prices than a number

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say i want to allow the users to enter the name of the city and the price of a thing (anything)

I need to know the percentage of (things) in that city that has less value for a field than an entered value:

i can search for a city like this:

```
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "city": "Paris"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

but i don't know how to do the other requirements, could you help me please?

Comment: Show the mapping of your index??

Comment: @Richa no mapping, the price is just number and the city is string.

Answer (score 0):

Suposedly [percentile-ranks-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-rank-aggregation.html) was intended as a means to achieve this

Example:

```
post <index>/<type>/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "term": {
         "city": "blore"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "rank": {
         "percentile_ranks": {
            "values": [
               31
            ],
            "field": "price"
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

But when testing I found that it is buggy  I believe is related to [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14851).

So the work around would be to calculate the percentage on client side once the document counts have been acquired using a query similar to as follows:

```
   post _search
{
   "filter": {
      "term": {
         "city": "blore"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "less_price_filter": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "price": {
                  "lt": 60
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

**Response**

```
  {
       "took": 1,
       "timed_out": false,
       "_shards": {
          "total": 5,
          "successful": 5,
          "failed": 0
       },
       "hits": {
          "total": 3,
          "max_score": 0,
          "hits": []
       },
       "aggregations": {
          "less_price_filter": {
             "doc_count": 2
          }
       }
    }
```

The percentage can be calculated on client-side by dividing `doc_count*100/total`.